# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver cannot be found by de Server

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc, file-permissions

I have a web application that has been working for ages now.. suddenly I get this message when I am trying to login:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

As I said before it has been working for over 3 years now… but the people who does the hosting for me have not been able to do anything… I have my driver on the WEB-INF folder and everything… can the folder’s permissions cause this problem? I have them set as 0744…any idea?

This is the screen shot of the WEB-INF folder:

[image]

I managed to login to the web application but the login jsp file is not working because the connection is not happening… here is the code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java"              import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<%@ page language="java" session="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Accesando a Vecinet</title>

</head>

<body>
<%

Connection conn = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn =    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/etoolsco_VecinetSM?user=etoolsco&password=xxxx");

ResultSet rsdoLogin = null;
PreparedStatement psdoLogin=null;

String uname=request.getParameter("j_username");
String upass=request.getParameter("j_password");
String message="User login successfully ";
%>


<% try
{
String sqlOption="SELECT * FROM logins where"
                +" usuario=? and clave=?";

psdoLogin=conn.prepareStatement(sqlOption);
psdoLogin.setString(1,uname);
psdoLogin.setString(2,upass);

rsdoLogin=psdoLogin.executeQuery();

if(rsdoLogin.next())
{
  session.setAttribute("usuario",rsdoLogin.getString("usuario"));
  session.setAttribute("clave",rsdoLogin.getString("clave"));
  session.setAttribute("nombre",rsdoLogin.getString("nombre"));
  session.setAttribute("apellido",rsdoLogin.getString("apellido"));
  session.setAttribute("role",rsdoLogin.getString("role"));
  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(7200);

  response.sendRedirect("Vecinetspace.jsp?error="+message);


}
else
{
  response.sendRedirect("error.jsp?error=");
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try{
     if(psdoLogin!=null){
         psdoLogin.close();
     }
     if(rsdoLogin!=null){
         rsdoLogin.close();
     }

     if(conn!=null){
      conn.close();
     }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

%>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the same login.jsp code for the application that is working:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<%@ page language="java" session="true" %>
<html>
<head><title>Login to CRD</title>

</head>

<body>

<%

Connection conn = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/etoolsco_labsmb?user=etoolsco&password=xxx");

ResultSet rsdoLogin = null;
PreparedStatement psdoLogin=null;

String uname=request.getParameter("j_username");
String upass=request.getParameter("j_password");
String message="User login successfully ";
%>


<% try
{
String sqlOption="SELECT * FROM logins where"
                +" usuario=? and clave=?";

psdoLogin=conn.prepareStatement(sqlOption);
psdoLogin.setString(1,uname);
psdoLogin.setString(2,upass);

rsdoLogin=psdoLogin.executeQuery();

 if(rsdoLogin.next())
 {
  session.setAttribute("usuario",rsdoLogin.getString("usuario"));
  session.setAttribute("clave",rsdoLogin.getString("clave"));
  session.setAttribute("nombre",rsdoLogin.getString("nombre"));
  session.setAttribute("apellido",rsdoLogin.getString("apellido"));
  session.setAttribute("role",rsdoLogin.getString("role"));
  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(600);

  response.sendRedirect("BMRspace.jsp?error="+message);


}
else
{
  response.sendRedirect("error.jsp?error=");
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try{
     if(psdoLogin!=null){
         psdoLogin.close();
     }
     if(rsdoLogin!=null){
         rsdoLogin.close();
     }

     if(conn!=null){
      conn.close();
     }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dang a half meg png people look at this on a phone ;)

Comment: Did you change your java classpath for the servlet container

Comment: thank u @DrewPierce for for the picture…. I have not changed anything, that is the issue.  Where I can check the class path? on the code?

Comment: java classpath is set a server level, right @DrewPierce? sorry if my question sounds a bit stupid, but I am not an expert...

Comment: I could help were at the java command line but each servlet container is outta my expertise

Comment: But i will look it up