# JDBC connector cannot be accessed by Server

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jar, web-inf

I am having issues trying to run a web application, that was working fine, but suddenly, stop working and now the server cannot find the JDBC connector that is located on the WEB-INF/lib… is there a way that can move the .jar file to another location? How can I say to the server where to find it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dang sheeyla that never resolved

Comment: Can you go back to that question and modify question to bump it up and not redocument the whole thing again. It is a duplicate question otherwise

Comment: create a new app with the GUI tool that you have. you have the other app that it works in. Grab its jar

Comment: If i remember right you stopped conversing

Comment: hi @DrewPierce no I didn`t stop conversing… I added the code of the other app and then I didn`t hear anything else… when you say GUI tool, what do you mean?...

Comment: I did grab its jar already… sorry @DrewPierce this is driving me mad and the hosting people, obviously they don`t know what is happening… I tried creating a new app duplicating it, but it didn´t work.

Comment: i would be happy to take a look but you'd obviously need to give me access. Most of it would be seeing if there was some missing checkbox as the web-info would have the right version non-corrupted and the jsp would contain 18 lines of code

Comment: one of the things you didn't answer before was whether or not this second app uses the same database as the one that works. I assume it does use a different database

Comment: possible duplicate of [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver cannot be found by de Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090984/com-mysql-jdbc-driver-cannot-be-found-by-de-server)